# Potential bug in Coded UI Test

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8.1, coded-ui-tests

I'm developing a Windows Phone (8.1) app.

For some reason, when I do Coded UI tests of the application and access the property "DisplayText" of a TextBox (XamlText object at runtime), I get the name of the textbox and not its contained text. According to the documentation for XamlText, I should get the text in the textbox. Have I found a bug here, or am I just misunderstanding something?
(To be exact, its displaying the AutomationProperty.Id value, when I read the DisplayText property).

Also, if I am misunderstanding something, how then could I go about getting the displayed text of a textbox during UI testing?

Thanks a lot in advance!

By the way, my code looks like this in XAML:

```
<Grid>
   **row definitions excluded to make code more tidy**
   <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlock}" 
           Text="{Binding Amount}" 
           AutomationProperties.Name="TransferAmountName" 
           AutomationProperties.AutomationId="TransferAmount"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And like this in C#:

```
var amountTransfered = UiMap.ScreenAmount.DisplayText;
```

the value of the variable "amountTransfered" is in this case "TransferAmount" and not the integer displayed in the UI in the TextBox.

Comment: Is it possible to show your code behind? Preferably your ScreenAmount property.

Comment: Please share code behind, without which we cannot suggest a solution.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not responding back. I havent had access to the code since then. I will have tomorrow, and will post an update. If we have fixed the problem, I'll try and see, if I can find out how they did it, while I was not there. Thanks!